# Java Setting Array values then loop through and set object field equal to array values

Tags: java, arrays, object

I have a pretty introductory question that I hope can get answered rather easily.

Currently I am trying to write something that queries my DB, returns result set (list of account id's) and then sets those account id's into an array so that I can populate an object with the values.

My object is going to be used as input into another method I have written but I can't figure out how I go about populating my account_id field on it with the values in my array that I returned in the result set. There doesn't seem to be any "setter" methods for lack of a better term on my array of type String.

I was able to get the array to populate with acct_id's from the result set and print them out so I know that I do have information coming back.

Below is the snippet I currently have, any help/improvements I could make would be greatly appreciated!

---

```
try {

    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
    st = connection.createStatement();
    rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

     List<Long> array = new ArrayList<Long>();


    while (rs.next()) {

        array.add((long) rs.getLong("acct_id"));  

        for (Integer i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(array.get(i));

            GetSummaryRequest request = new GetSummaryRequest();

            request.accountKey =  new AccountDTO(array[i]); 

        }
    }


    } catch (SQLException e) {

        System.out.println("Connection failed.");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;

    }
 if (rs.next()) {

     System.out.println(rs.getString(1));

 } else 

     System.out.print("Failed. Try again");

}
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? request.accountKey = array[i];

Comment: I tried this first but I am getting an issue with it saying it cannot convery the string type array to the object that my "GetSummaryRequest" is.

Comment: Is `acct_id` just one id or a list of ids separated by `\n`?

Comment: Well the query I am executing returns back acct_id's from a table, so I am not sure the default form in which that comes back, but yes it is a list of id's

Comment: If GetSummaryRequest.accountKey is a String, the sentence i put in the first comment is valid. Each position of array is a String, and you can use that to set/get the value: array[i] = "str"; or String otherStr = array[i];

Comment: What's the datatype of **accountKey**

Comment: Thinking about this more, it is a DTO object, so it looks like I am going to have to do something like this: request.accountKey = new AccountDTO(array[i])

Comment: Update: I had my information wrong, the account id's coming back are of type Long, I have updated my code snippet, I am geting the error "The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to List<Long>" when I try to set my accountKey

Comment: Also, my constructor on AccountDTO is set up to take in a (long accountID)

Answer (score 1):

If my understanding is correct you may need the code below which is used to store all the account id's inside an array and you can use this to pass as a parameter to another method.

```
 ArrayList<GetSummaryRequest> array1=new ArrayList<GetSummaryRequest>(); 
 GetSummaryRequest request = new GetSummaryRequest();  

  while (rs.next()) 
  {
        request=new GetSummaryRequest();
        request.accountKey=rs.getString("acct_id");
        array1.add(request);            

    }
```

Now you have ArrayList of GetSummaryRequest with accountKey for each object.

Comment: Placing the `request=new GetSummaryRequest();` is what makes it work. If it's outside it just stores the first `request.setItem("acct_id");` and repeats that over and over. Good answer

Answer (score 0):

if i understand correctly accountkey is integer right?
you can use Integer.parseint('your string!') class to convert the string to int.
i hope it helps

Comment: just remember to pass a member of the array to parseint function. any way what kinda of object is accountkey?

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all , storing newline separated values in one column is not a good practice. This is against atomicity principle and will lead you to problems soon - ex., total number of accounts? how do you find it?
2. Once you convince yourself with this, you can use only one loop like this

   ```
   List<GetSummaryRequest> summaryRequests = new ArrayList<GetSummaryRequest>();
   while (rs.next()) {

      String em = rs.getString("acct_id");
      GetSummaryRequest request = new GetSummaryRequest();
      request.accountKey = em; 
      summaryRequests.add(request);
   }
   return summaryRequests;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need something like that:

```
// First you get all ids
List<String> accountsIds = new ArrayList<String>();
while (rs.next()) {
    accountsIds.add(rs.getString("acct_id"));
}

// Then iterate ids
for (String id : accountsIds) {
    GetSummaryRequest request = new GetSummaryRequest();
    request.accountKey = id;
}
```